# Display Images from Clearbit in Angular App

Tags: angular

I need to display Images from Clearbit website using Angular App.

Trying this but image is not displaying.

```html
<div style="justify-content: center; display:flex;height: 70px">
  <img src="{{https://logo.clearbit.com/suzy.com/}}" class="issuer-img" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your {{ ...}} around source, you can display the image

```html
<div style="justify-content: center; display:flex;height: 70px">
  <img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/suzy.com" class="issuer-img" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img class="issuer-img" [style.background-image]="'url(' + ({{issuer.imageURL}} | async) + ')'">
```